# How would I connect to two databases in laravel 5.2, one SQL and one SQL Server?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm looking online and the only examples are of the same type of database.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define configuration for your connections in `config/database.php`, just make sure you fill in all required parameters:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => '',
        'port' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => '',
        'collation' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => '', 
        'database' => '',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
],
```

Then you need to set one of those connections as the default connection Eloquent uses in `config/database.php':

```
'default' => 'mysql', //use mysql by default
```

`MySQL` connection will be used by default by all your models and queries.

You can change the connection given model uses by setting it's `$connection` attribute:

```
class User extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
}
```

You can also change the connection used when you execute queries using `DB` facade by calling the `connection()` method:

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('some_table')->get();
```

Comment: Yeah I've done that, i just  assumed there was something i had missed as i won't get a connection to a SQL Server for a few days! thanks

Comment: Isn't this all in documentation? I mean I like the sum up + comments, just asking. (+1)